# how can i get Total like From A post in Facebook with Graph Api?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

how to get total likes a post from  graph api url ?

Here [This Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Return:
**array of objects containing the id and name fields. Requesting with summary=1 will also return a summary object containing the total_count of likes.**

Comment: Please Vote up My question . thankk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the [FB API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) try fetching likes for a post, i used 700182169998352

the "/700182169998352/likes" return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "663945278",
      "name": "Irene Olsson Wikler"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002437916716",
      "name": "Frida Braxell"
    },
    {
      "id": "1135121633",
      "name": "Rex Leopold Olsson"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTEzNTEyMTYzMw==",
      "before": "NjYzOTQ1Mjc4"
    }
  }
}
```

the "/700182169998352/likes?summary=1" return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "663945278",
      "name": "Irene Olsson Wikler"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002437916716",
      "name": "Frida Braxell"
    },
    {
      "id": "1135121633",
      "name": "Rex Leopold Olsson"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "MTEzNTEyMTYzMw==",
      "before": "NjYzOTQ1Mjc4"
    }
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 3
  }
}
```

so by adding the `?summary=1` you get an extra part in the json result named summary,
and containng the total_count, in my case 3