# Extracting the like and share count on my blog

Tags: java, javascript, facebook

I have a blog http://techieme.in and I want to write a java code to fetch the like count on the blog.

I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution. I have code to extract all the text information and images from the posts.

When I checked the source of the blog, I see that the like count is probably generated using some javascript code. So, just wondering if there is any way of extracting the count of FB likes from  a blog in java code?

Comment: you could parse the `html` and get the number of likes using `regex`

Comment: better ask facebook directly per api [see similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url)

Answer (score 0):

Use a web crawler like this one here http://freetools.webmasterworld.com/tools/crawler-google-sitemap-generator/ to get a list of URL's of your site.

Then you can use a comma separated list of URL's to get a list of results from this URL.

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.almaruf.com,http://yahoo.com,http://google.com