# get likes and comments of facebook post after sharing it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

User sharing contents in facebook like this,

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://myexample.com
```

After share complete, i want to fetch all comments and likes of that post.

Is it returning `post_id`? so may be we can fetch comments using post id by graph api?

How should i do that in php?

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061937/facebook-api-best-way-to-get-like-share-comment-count-for-a-page-group-post  it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The sharer.php does not return anything. You can only use the Share Dialog if you want to get a Post ID, but:

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and
>   has granted `publish_actions`.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response