# How do I get the likes number from facebook for a given url?

Tags: facebook, button, twitter, google-plus, facebook-like

A url http://www.cnn.com/2014/03/15/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-passenger-vignettes/index.html?hpt=hp_t1

How can I get the facebook like number or twitter posts number or google+ number from this url?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about computer programming.

Comment: maybe you wanna take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url ..
even though it might be different with what you want, it might leads you to the right dirrection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following FQL via the Graph API:

```
select url, like_count from link_stat where url='http://edition.cnn.com/2014/03/15/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-passenger-vignettes/index.html'
```

like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url%2C%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fedition.cnn.com%2F2014%2F03%2F15%2Fworld%2Fasia%2Fmalaysia-airlines-passenger-vignettes%2Findex.html%27

which gives the result

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "http://edition.cnn.com/2014/03/15/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-passenger-vignettes/index.html", 
      "like_count": 28529
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It can get like_count from facebook.But how about twitter and google+ ?