# Final Checklist/Written Approval for Facebook Graph Use

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using this endpoint

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=

to collect the number of likes of specific urls. I want to display this information on a front end but do not want to make unnecessary API calls (there are over 25,000 posts). I would like to retrieve this information and store it so it can be retrieved from our database. On some pages, there will be over 10 of these accessible view a hover effect from a mouse. I would prefer to not have to load the page up with javascript targeted elements everywhere. It would be much easier to have the information stored and updated periodically. We will not be going over the impression limit or even coming close, but I would like to just make sure I'm not doing anything that will get me in trouble.

I would like permission to utilize this data to help increase pathways between our site and Facebook to allow people to share the page. I'm pretty sure we're doing everything correct but would just like to make sure and not step on anyone's toes.

I read through the checklist here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/

however I don't know if what I'm doing would be considered an app....? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here: [How do I get the likes number from facebook for a given url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677398/how-do-i-get-the-likes-number-from-facebook-for-a-given-url/22681930#22681930)

You can also use FQL queries with IN lists to query multiple URLs at once. Please consider that a FQL statement can have a maximum length of 2048 characters.

```
select url, like_count from link_stat where url in ('URL1', 'URL2', ...)
```

The "cheklist" you linked is completely unneccessary, because you don't need to submit anything related to OpenGraph objects or actions. You can even use the functionality without using an Access Token, because the `link_stat` table is public (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)