# Notification on new like on facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I receive notification when some one likes my Facebook Page or Comments on some post ? Is there any graph or FQL query ? 
I have tested the rss feeds page , they dont seem to get updated frequently , have also tested the following FQL query , doesnt seem to work

```
SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href FROM notification WHERE recipient_id=me()
```

Comment: I donot just need the count , but need to know who liked it also .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of likes using a query[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url)].

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=likes

In PHP, for example, you can get the result like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=likes');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$likes = $obj["likes"];
```

You can poll that count, say, once every 15 seconds. If the count is greater than the last poll, you can i.e. sound a buzzer on your desk using Arduino[[2](http://www.fritz-hut.com/2012/08/30/php-serialclass-with-arduino-raspberrypi/)]:

```
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("<ding>");

$serial->deviceClose();
```

Comment: I also need to know who liked the facebook page .

Comment: I think for privacy reasons, Facebook doesn't tell you everyone who likes the page, since you are not actually connected to those people.