# Request to get total count of Facebook page likes in v2.3 API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Previously I was using FQL for this, but this is deprecated as of v2.1 and I'm moving over to v2.3 using the graph edge "likes".

Here is my URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/<page_id>/likes?access_token=<access_token>&summary=true
```

This returns detail JSON with paging info - but it omits the **total_count** which is supposed to be returned when "summary=true" is used as described in the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes:) - you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Anyone stumbling onto this answer now (April 2016) will get frustrated because the accepted answer no longer works in v2.6

**?fields=likes** and **/likes** now return the same result -> the pages that the page likes.

To get the number of fans, you now need to use **fields=fan_count**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pepsius/?fields=fan_count&access_token=<access_token>
```

As you can see above, you can also make the request directly with the pagename, no need to fetch the pageID.

Comment: Correct, I have updated this to be the right answer now.

Comment: You are a life saver. This is NO WHERE in their documentation!

Comment: My `<page_id>` is a website URL. This doesn't work for URLs `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (fan_count) on node type (URL)`

Comment: @Marie-LouiseJournocode Sorry for the late reply. You need to create an app and then make a call to get the access_token. More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens

Comment: Sorry @StephenBugsKamenar I think this is only intended for actual Facebook pages.

Comment: @NativePaul You are awesome. Thank you so much for providing this solution!

Comment: Thanks, not only is this not in the documentation you have to manually enter it in the graph explorer to test it out.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for the total number of people that have liked the page or what the page has liked?

For example.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/56381779049/likes?access_token=<access_token>&summary=true
```

Will return what the Page PepsiUS has liked.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/56381779049?fields=likes&access_token=<access_token>
```

Will return the total number of people that have liked the page.

```
{"likes": 32804486, 
"id": "56381779049"}
```

Varified here [PepsiUS](https://www.facebook.com/PepsiUS?fref=ts)

Comment: It's the second one, i.e. ?fields=likes.

Comment: I believe the difference is PageID/Likes is an Endpoint that will return other pages the target page has liked. PageID?fields=Likes is an counts the Edges to pages/users.

Comment: Thanks it is very easy

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @NativePaul

I spent almost two days to find a solution to get the Facebook Fan Page likes counter in numeric value to a shortcode. So I have amended a code I got from this link: http://www.internoetics.com/2015/07/13/display-number-facebook-page-likes-wordpress-php/

And amended it to work with the fan_count fields and here is the code for your reference:

```html
/*
 Display the Number of Facebook Page Likes in Plain Text with WordPress Shortcode (and PHP)
 Shortcode: [fbpagelikes id="" appid="" appsecret="" cache="" n="1"]
*/


function internoetics_fb_pagelikes($atts) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => 'kenryscom',
    'appid' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'appsecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'n' => 1,
    'cache' => 3600 * 24 * 1
  ), $atts));

 $fbcounthash = md5("$url.$cache.$appid.$appsecret.$n");
 $fbcountrecord = 'fblikes_' . $fbcounthash;
 $cachedposts = get_transient($fbcountrecord);
 if ($cachedposts !== false) {
 return $cachedposts;

  } else {

  $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '?fields=fan_count&access_token=' . $appid . '|' . $appsecret;
  $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
  $json_output = json_decode($json);
 
  if($json_output->fan_count) {
   $fan_count = $json_output->fan_count;
   if ($n) $fan_count = number_format($fan_count);
   set_transient($fbcountrecord, $fan_count, $cache);
   return $fan_count;
    } else {
   return 'Unavailable';
  }
 }
}
add_shortcode('fbpagelikes','internoetics_fb_pagelikes');
```

You have to add the above code to the theme functions file and use the Shortcode anywhere as mentioned in the beginning of the code.