# Get Facebook Pages likes total_count (PHP, Facebook Graph API)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to get the total number of likes for different Facebook pages, like this one for example : https://www.facebook.com/LeoMessi/

I have implemented the following code :

```
<?php
// Pass session data over.
session_start();

// Include the required dependencies.
require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );

// Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK v5.
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => '**********',
    'app_secret'            => '**********',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get('/176063032413299?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)', $_SESSION['access_token']);
    var_dump($response);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

It works, but it does not return the total_count property. I don'to how to access this property for any Facebook Page. Could you help me ?

Comment: You’re aware that you are asking for the pages liked _by_ that page here …? If you want the number of users that liked _this_ page, then the relevant field is `fan_count`.

Comment: Yes absolutly. I have found the "fan_count" solution just after having posted the question ;-) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everybody, I just founded the solution just after having posted my question. And the solution is just here : [Request to get total count of Facebook page likes in v2.3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702192/request-to-get-total-count-of-facebook-page-likes-in-v2-3-api)

To get the number of fans, you now need to use `fields=fan_count.`

So I just replace

```
/176063032413299?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)
```

With

```
/176063032413299?fields=fan_count
```

And it returns

```
["fan_count"]=> int(88899488)
```

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score -3):

Modify field as :

```
{page-id}?fields=fan_count
```