# How to get URL likes on Facebook in 2021

Tags: facebook

Is a JSON response from Facebook still available? for links like [my-websites.com](https://my-website.com)?

I tried these answers but they no longer work: [Getting the Facebook like/share count for a given URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url)

I found https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/link but there are no JavaScript - JSON examples.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/url, `engagement` field. But the request will need an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @CBroe.
The documentations is here: [developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/url)

The JavaScript and JSON:

```
 var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=engagement&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&id=WEBSITE-URL"; 

 $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   console.log(json);
 });
```